# Why epsilon and delta can be changed in the definition of continuity when the function is limited in an interval

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

We have a function $f:[a,b]\to \Bbb R$, where $[a,b]$ is an interval bounded by the real straight line. Now someone writes the definition of continuity at $x \in [a,b]$ but makes a mistake. He writes $\delta$ in stead of $\varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon$ instead of $\delta$. So the definition changes: 
for every $\delta > 0$ there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that if $x \in [a,b], |x - x_0| < \delta$ then $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \varepsilon$.

Now we have to prove that this definition is satisfied if and only if the function is bounded by $[a,b]$.

How can I prove this?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose you choose $\delta$ to be very large; say, larger than the length of the entire interval.  What does the existence of $\epsilon$ tell you then?

Comment: I'm sorry.. I don't get it..

Comment: Maybe you just have gotten so used to thinking of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ as small, you can't go in the other direction.  Rewrite it as: for every $D>b-a$ there exists an $E>10^{100}$ such that if $|x-x_0|<D$ then $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<E$.